# How to position an icon in a metro-like web GUI? (images included)

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple, light weight, GUI similar to [Microsoft Metro UI](http://gadgetmix.com/articles/windows-8-review/). It is comprised of a set of  elements which are **floating** to make it flexibly re-sizable according to the size of the screen:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Index2</title>
<style type="text/css">
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
html{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
div.tiles{
    background-color:black;
    padding:50px;
}
div.tiles div{
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#666;
    display:marker;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
div.tiles div:hover{
    transition:background-color 1s;
    -moz-transition:background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 1s;
    background-color:#060;
    -moz-transform:rotate(6deg);
}
div.tiles div.icon{
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:red;
}
div.tiles div.w1{width:25px;}
div.tiles div.w2{width:80px;}
div.tiles div.w3{width:160px;}
div.tiles div.w4{width:190px;}

div.tiles div.h1{height:25px;}
div.tiles div.h2{height:80px;}
div.tiles div.h3{height:160px;}
div.tiles div.h4{height:190px;}
</style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tiles clearfix">
    <div class="w4 h2">
    mattberg@live.com <div class="icon">icon</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="w4 h2">
    RSS
    </div>  
    <div class="w4 h2">
    13
    </div>
    <div class="w2 h2">
    IE
    </div>  
    <div class="w2 h2">
    Photo
    </div>  
    <div class="w4 h2">
    Now Playing
    </div>  
    <div class="w4 h2">
    Photo <div class="icon">icon</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="w2 h2">
    Shop
    </div>
    <div class="w2 h2">
    SMS
    </div>  
    <div class="w4 h2">
    Weather <div class="icon">icon</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="w4 h2">
    Investment
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
    <div class="w1 h1">
    Lilly
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem positioning the icon elements in the divs. This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

In other words I want to be able to position the elements in the tiled div elements absolutely. I tried various CSS positioning techniques (relative, fixed, absolute) but couldn't solve it. I suspect it's because the tiles are **floating** elements?

How can I be able to design the contents of each tile regardless of its position in the web page?

Comment: agree! A great example of a wonderfully explained question.

Comment: @AlexStack You are my hero.  May I please use this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the tile divs relatively positioned and icons absolutely positioned.

```
.tiles > div {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.tiles > div .icon {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

With relative positioning the tile div becomes a [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) for its absolute positioned children. Relative elements are positioned [just like](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position) normal (static) elements when *top* and *left* are zero or undefined.